# My email input in my form has a required tag to use the built in html5 required function but it just doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

Im working on one of my 5 projects in the freecodecamp Responsive Web Design course (the survey project) and I am trying to use the built in required function in html5 in my email input but it isn't working, when I click enter rather than giving the little popup asking for a valid email address with an @ in it, nothing happens at all. Im a very new developer so humor me if im asking a dumb question but I can't seem to figure it out on my own.

HTML:

```
<form id="survey-form">
          <label for="name">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-inputs" id="name" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-inputs" id="email" placeholder="Enter A Valid Email Adress" required> 

</form>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Whereas it would normally show the popup asking for a valid email adress for me nothing happens or pops up when I click enter. Sorry should have included that. Will edit the post.

Comment: Do note that an input needs to have a `name` attribute to be included in a form submission. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally validation doesn't run unless you try to submit the form.

Add a submit button after your input element and try the same code. The end result could be something like this:

```html
<form id="survey-form">
    <label for="name">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-inputs" id="name" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-inputs" id="email" placeholder="Enter A Valid Email Adress" name="email" required> 
    <button type="submit">Submit Me</button>
</form>
```

If you require to send the form to a specific file to do the submission process you could add an `action` attribute to the `form` tag but from what you are saying that's outside of what you're currently studying.

**EDIT based on Tieson T.'s comment**

I added the `name="email"` to the email input in the code example.

Comment: Would also need to add `name="email"` to the email input, or it's not considered a successful control.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I did have a name before but I was removing/changing random stuff before to see if it would have any affect. Anyway thanks that helped alot.